# Create two foreign key references to same table with unique composite index to one of them

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, referential-integrity

All items in the `items` table have a category that can be derived from the `item_category` table.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| items                                       |
+---------------------------------------------+
| id                 | PK                     |
+--------------------+------------------------+
| item_category_id   | FK(item_categories.id) |
+--------------------+------------------------+
```

The `item_category` table references itself. I wanted to create a category->sub-category->sub-sub-category etc. system. I don't know how many nested sub-categories there will be so I thought my best bet would be to enclose that structure in a single table. If the `item_category_id` is `NOT NULL` then it has a parent, otherwise it is a super-category and does not have a parent.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| item_categories                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
| id               | PK                     |
+------------------+------------------------+
| item_category_id | FK(item_categories.id) |
+------------------+------------------------+
```

This is where my question lies. The `doll_item` table is a pivot table. Basically a `doll` can have many items and an `item` can belong to many dolls. But there's more to it than that. I want to make sure that for every `doll`, in the `doll_item` table, its corresponding `item` comes from a unique category.

I have tried to pull in the `item_category_id` for the `item` in each row; however, I fear that this relation does not enforce that the `item_id` and `item_category_id` from the `items` table necessarily come from the same row. Without this requirement, the addition of the two latter rows in the `doll_item` table is pointless.

Is it possible to enforce this using MySQL?

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| doll_item                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| doll_id              | FK(dolls.id)                   |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+
| item_id              | FK(items.id)                   |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+
| item_category_id     | FK(items.item_category_id)     |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+
| unique(doll_item.doll_id, doll_item.item_category_id) |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Clarification: You also have an `dolls` table, right? Question: When you say "pivot" table do you mean "many-to-many join" table? Question: Many such join tables have a compound (unique) primary key on the two `id` columns, in your case `(doll_id, item_id)`. Is there some reason you can't do that, and therefore collect your unique `item_category_id` from the `items` table?

Comment: Clarification: Yes, there is a `dolls` table. Answer: Yes, by "pivot" table I do mean that there is a many-to-many join table; this is the `doll_item` table. Answer: I need a more specific constraint than that. I need for each `doll` there to be a unique `item` for each `item_category`. To illustrate the point, lets say I have a 'trousers' item. I don't want to allow a doll to have two different types of trousers on it. This is a dressup game so it will look weird if a doll has two pairs of trousers on. What do you mean "therefore collect your unique `item_category_id` from the `items` table?"

Comment: Off-topic but I can't help myself: if you are planning to allow an arbitrary depth of sub-categories, please consider reading [this excellent thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/192220/1446005).

Comment: Thanks! Really interesting from what I understand. Although it seems that with adjacency relations nodes can have multiple immediate parents which would be an issue for my architecture. Or have I misunderstood because I saw the implementation of breadcrumbs that is effectively analogous to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make sure that for every doll in the `doll_item` table, [every] corresponding `item` comes from a [different] category

Use a composite `UNIQUE KEY`.

> I fear that this relation does not enforce that the `item_id` and `item_category_id` from the `items` table necessarily come from the same row

Use a compound `FOREIGN KEY`.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  item_category_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX (id, item_category_id) -- see note below
);

CREATE TABLE doll_item (
  doll_id INT NOT NULL,
  item_id INT NOT NULL,
  item_category_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (doll_id, item_id),

  UNIQUE KEY (doll_id, item_category_id),

  FOREIGN KEY (item_id, item_category_id)
    REFERENCES item (id, item_category_id)

);
```

---

*note: [in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)*

Comment: This looks perfect! Thanks :) ... with regards to your note do you mean that I need a `unique composite key` in my `item` table? Or do you mean that `id` must be the first field before `item_category_id` in the database schema? @randomseed

Comment: It only means that the two referenced columns must be covered by an index of any type (regular, unique, primary key, whatnot). The part about them having to be "listed as the *first columns* [in the index definition]" means that an index on `item(id, item_category_id, another_column)` would do the job as well. See also this manual page for a related [discussion on multi-column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Comment: I see ... thanks a bunch...your answers have been incredibly helpful - I appreciate it a lot!